# emacs: replace 'x' characters from the same place in every line

Tags: emacs

I know how to delete the x characters from a specific place for every line in a region. My question is slightly different: I want to replace all the characters with something else.

Specifically, I want to replace 4 characters of : from the 6-9 columns of each line in the file with -.

Is there any key binding available to do this without using regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "*from a specific place*"? Can you give an example?

Comment: I mean replace 4 characters of : from the 6-9 columns of each line in the file with -.

Comment: Please update your question to specify that. That's apparently an important part of what you are asking. Comments can be removed at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x cua-rectangle-mark-mode`, use arrows and other movement keys to define your rectangle, then `M-r` (`cua-replace-in-rectangle`), which works similarly to `replace-regexp`.  I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for the other rectangle command set, but I like cua-rect much more, and despite the name it doesn't pull in the rest of CUA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query Replace in emacs.
**M-% string RET newstring RET**
Replace some occurrences of string with newstring.

Comment: I want to restrict in a rectangle. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string-rectangle` command:

- Mark one corner of the rectangle
- Move to the opposite corner
- Type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
- Type your replacement text, followed by <kbd>RET</kbd>